# How does the Torrent protocol connect directly between two peers?

Tags: networking, router, bittorrent

It seams that the standard way of doing p2p[over the internet] is to port forward the router to accept external connections via TCP, or to use an external[hosted] server to relay[peer1 --> server --> peer2] the data, but how exactly[using what methods] does the torrent protocol achive a direct connection to another peer after obtaining the information it needs to do so[ip address, port etc..] from the tracker?

Comment: any end-to-end connection requires some part of the protocol to know to where it connects; hence... Yes, there is direct connection.

Answer (score 1):

The tracker knows the public IP of each Peer. In the early years you must forward the TCP port used by torrent to your PC on the router by configuring TCP-Port-Forwarding. Nowadays this could be done with UPnP so you don't need to configure your router manually.